# How to authenticate to the '/dev' URL of a google apps script web app

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, basic-authentication

I am having difficulty with a RESTful `GET` after  [Deploying a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app)

The documentation at that link says:

> Once you click Deploy, you'll see a new dialog with a message indicating that your project has been successfully deployed as a web app.
>
> This dialog provides two important URLs for your app:

1. *... concerns the `exec` URL ...*  I am able to use this form without problem, having selected, **Execute the app as:** `Me` and **Who has access to the app:** `Anyone,even anonymous`

> 2. The second is the link labeled latest code and ends in /dev. This URL can only be accessed by users who have edit access to the script. This instance of the app always runs the most recently saved code — not necessarily a formal version — and is intended for quick testing during development.

To use that second link (from Postman or Wget, etc) I expected to need to use basic auth like ...

`https://aladdin:sesame@script.google.com/macros/s/AKfyuglyuglyuglyS6i-g/dev`

... but Google just returns a log in page.

If it is possible to do this, how do I do it?

*Update:*

I should perhaps mention I want this just to avoid repeatedly "publishing" new version, new version, new version, etc, during a brief phase of integration testing -- which is why I haven't researched OAuth for this purpose, as @tehhowch rightly suggested.

Comment: Google generally expects OAuth credentials / tokens. Have you tried with OAuth?

Comment: @tehhowch -- I was hoping to avoid the huge amount of time it takes to pick through the docs trying to figure out which method applies, while unsure if Google even permits that kind of access.

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script

Comment: @Tanaike, that is a brilliant document deserving of a much broader audience! It certainly look as though  '/dev' URL access forces me to use access tokens. I'll work through it and get back to you.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad for your reply. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike 's document is a god-send!

Comment: @Dimu Designs Thank you. I'm honored.